# get quite a lot error when install spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/01/08 15:27:58 WARN SparkContext: Support for Java 7 is deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0
17/01/08 15:28:03 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/01/08 15:28:08 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/01/08 15:28:08 WARN SparkContext: Support for Java 7 is deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 43, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 307, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 179, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 246, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Chenhuis-MacBook-Pro.local: Chenhuis-MacBook-Pro.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1475)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress(Utils.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:920)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localHostName(Utils.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Chenhuis-MacBook-Pro.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1471)
    ... 22 more


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 47, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 307, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 179, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 246, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
  File "/Users/ChenhuiChen/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I download the Spark from website, couldn't handle it properly in my Computer.... I didn't do anything and just open /bin/pyspark.

Search online long time for solution and no result.

Do I need to "build the Spark JARs"?

Comment: Which OS do you have on your computer? What have you done in order to install spark? What did you execute which cause the errors you attached?

Comment: It looks like you're on a macbook. Have you tried following these steps:
http://genomegeek.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/how-to-install-apache-spark-on-mac-os-x.html

It is also available on homebrew:  _brew install apache-spark_

Comment: @Yaron Thanks for pointing out how to ask questions in detail ! For question's useful, my system is Sierra. I just download spark and install it, and didn't do anything else.

Comment: @O.Gindele Thanks for the website!

Comment: Did you get it to work by installing java 8?

Comment: @O.Gindele Yes. I followed the steps to delete Java 7 to downgrade the version. Unfortunately I don't have older version and had to install it again.. Then it works. Thanks for taking care!!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the JAVA 7 (it is really bad idea), and install java 8..

There are steps how to delete the java.
[Trouble installing Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353477/trouble-installing-pyspark)